# Roots of $x^n - 1$ in an algebraically closed field of prime characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, divisibility

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$ , and let $n$ be a positive integer.

Consider $ g := x^n - 1 \in F[x]$

Is it true that $ g$ has distinct roots in $F$ if and only if $p$ does not divides $n$ ?

Here is my argument, please could you tell me whether it is correct:

Note roots of g are distinct if and only if $\mathrm{hcf}(g,g') = 1 $ .

Suppose $\beta \in F$ is a root of $g$  .

Now   $ \beta^n = 1$, so $\beta \neq 0$ .

Then $g'(\beta) = n \beta^{-1} = 0 $    iff     $p \mid n $

unless there is something wrong with how i am checking, i can't find any counterexamples for finite fields (where roots exist)

EDIT:

i think the statement is correct, at least i have found something which implies this in a book "Classical Galois Theory"

EDIT 2:

Noting $(a-b)^p = a^p - b^p $ in a field of characteristic p (what Dilip said)

then $$p \mid n \implies n = mp \implies x^n - 1 = (x^m-1)^p$$

and the polynomial on the RHS has only repeated roots. Can someone show me the other way?

Comment: you seem to be concluding exactly backwards.

Comment: $(a-b)^p = a^p-b^p$ in a field of characteristic $p$. What does this tell you about $x^n-1 = x^{mp}-1$?

Comment: so are you saying we reduce it to the cases 1,2,3,...,p-1 ?

Comment: can someone tell me whether the proof is right or wrong, and explain the error to me please?

Comment: Noting $(a-b)^p = a^p - b^p $ in a field of characteristic p (what Dilip said)

then $$p \mid n \implies n = mp \implies x^n - 1 = (x^m-1)^p$$ 

and the polynomial on the RHS has only repeated roots. Can someone show me the other way?

Comment: Dear user, Your argument looks perfectly fine to me.  I don't really see what the other commenters are worried about.  (Yes, it *is* true that you *can* use the formula $(a-b)^p = a^p - b^p$ to investigate your question in the case that $p | n$, but you don't *need* to.)  Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument shows that $g$ and $g'$ have a common root exactly when $p | n$,
and as you observe, this implies that $g$ has a multiple root exactly when $p | n$.  So your argument is correct.

---

Aside: This statement is very well-known. A useful adjective in this context is *separable* (which just means "has distinct roots").  You might have more luck finding this statement in textbooks if you look for discussions of when cyclotomic polynomials are separable.  (The polynomial $x^n - 1$ has a factorization as a product of cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(x)$, as $d$ ranges over the divisors of $n$, so $x^n - 1$ is separable iff all $\Phi_d(x)$ are separable for $d | n$.   Now (almost?) *every* Galois theory text should have the statement that $\Phi_d(x)$ is separable iff $p \not\mid d$.)

Comment: Thanks Matt you are amazing.